# Better solution to handle required method of a protocol not implemented

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, datasource, protocols

When the required method of a protocol hasn't be implemented Xcode just give a warning

`Warning: method 'xxx' in protocol 'xxx' not implemented`

I have a customized view works like `UITableView` who has a `dataSource` property. To ensure the dataSource is not nil and is respond to the method I do this

```
NSAssert(self.dataSource != nil, @"menu's dataSource shouldn't be nil");
if ([self.dataSource respondsToSelector:@selector(menu:numberOfRowsInColumn:)]) {
    return [self.dataSource menu:self
            numberOfRowsInColumn:self.currentSelectedMenudIndex];
} else {
    NSAssert(0 == 1, @"required method of dataSource protocol should be implemented");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering whether there is a more elegant way to handle the missing of required method?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That solutions looks good to me as the assertion can be disabled for production code making it a developer-only sanity check.

If the protocol could be implemented by third-party code (i.e. plug-ins of some kind) then an exception should be raised instead.

However a *slightly* easier assertion to code and understand would be simply:

```
NSAssert(NO, @"blah blah blah");
```